# Twiiter bootstrap 3 Tab Dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, tabs

I'm trying to make two dropdowns.  Second dropdown doesn't works. Can anyone help me?

So I have tab panel with 2 dropdowns. Each of them have own dropdown list

Here is code: http://jsfiddle.net/xY8gv/

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">   
        <li class="dropdown active">
            <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Main Settings <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1">
                <li class="active"><a href="#general" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#knowledge" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#education" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Education</a></li>           
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="myTabDrop2" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account Settings <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop2">
                <li class="active"><a href="#profile-photo" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Notifications</a></li>
                <li><a href="#email-password" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">E-mail & Password</a></li>
                <li><a href="#social" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Social</a></li>         
            </ul>   
        </li>
    </ul>


    <!-- MyTabContent -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- Main settings -->
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="general">
            <p>Main Settings</p>    
        </div><!-- Main settings end -->

        <!-- Contacts settings -->
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="contact">
            <p>Contacts Settings</p>            
        </div><!-- Contacts settings ends -->

        <!-- Knowledge settings -->
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="knowledge">
            <p>Kmowledgde Settings</p>
        </div><!-- Knowledge settings ends -->      

        <!-- Education settings -->
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="education">
            <p>Education Settings</p>
        </div><!-- Education settings ends -->

        <!-- Notifications settings -->       
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="notifications">   
           <p>Notifications settings</p> 
        </div><!-- Notifications settings --> 

    </div><!-- MyTabContent ends -->
```

Comment: in my computer it's working normally...

Comment: Account Settings? > Notifications? DOES IT WORKS?

Comment: works fine for me in Chrome

Comment: You just said in your question that doesn't works. Can you be more specific explaining what is the exact problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup had a bunch of things wrong..

- Notifications was pointing to 'profile-photo'
- You had more that one `active` tab and tab-pane
- Why was the `in` class used everywhere?
- There was no content for 'social'

Once it's all cleaned up it works fine...

http://www.bootply.com/123488